# bootstrap-datetimepicker is not picking up last 6 days date on server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap-datetimepicker for selecting the from date and to date in my MVC project but it is not picking up last 6 days date on server but locally it is working fine.

Please find the my code below,

```
$('#textFromDate').datetimepicker({

    ignoreReadonly: true,
    maxDate: 'now'

});
$("#textToDate").datetimepicker({

    ignoreReadonly: true,
    maxDate: 'now'
});
```

Kindly help on it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: You checked that the server and your local machine have the correct date, time and time-zone settings?

Comment: I have not checked but picker is picking up last 7th date and working properly.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer : Thanks your comment helped me.I have changed default format to DD/MM/YYYY and its working.